# Websocket Server Endpoints not working on tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, websocket

I am new to Java so any help is appreciated. I started off building a simple project with java EE 8 websocket endpoints and tomcat 10 using Intellij, basiclly following the same code structure as all other applications

```
@ServerEndpoint("/chat")
public class WebsocketServer{
    
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(){}
    
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(){}
    
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(){}
}
```

dependency was also included in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

html code

```
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded/chat')
```

However when I run the server on my Intellij tomcat. The index.html give an error in the console without any explaination. I believe this was because my websocket server was never started but I'm not sure why this happened. Any help is appreciated.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/demo_war_exploded/chat' failed:
(anonymous)
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't going to work.

The application is written to the Java EE 8 API but Tomcat 10 implements the Jakarta EE 9 API where all the package names were changed.

You need to do one of two things:

1. Use Tomcat 9 rather than Tomcat 10
2. Switch to the Jakarta WebSocket 2.0 API and change all your imports to use `jakarta.websocket` rather than `javax.websocket`.